# defining new color

Tags: color

I'm using

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

to use *RoyalPurple* color, but now I wanted to redefine it to

```
\definecolor{light-RoyalPurple}{RoyalPurple}{0.85}
```

But I get

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color
>   model `RoyalPurple'.

that doesn't happen with

```
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}
```

So I think that \definecolor just works with "normal" colors... how to solve it?

Comment: The first argument has to be a `color model`, that is, `html`, `rgb`, or whatever format you'd like to provide your definition of the color in.

Comment: @carsten I suppose it, the problem I would like to solve is how to do the same with the others colors :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not working because you're giving the command an unexpected value. The second argument of `\definecolor` expects one of the color models from this list:

```
natural, rgb, cmy, cmyk, hsb, gray, RGB, HTML, HSB, Gray
```

That's why `gray` worked in your case. Try replacing that with `blue` and you'll get the same error. If you want a lighter version of `RoyalPurple`, use `\colorlet`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\colorlet{lRP}{RoyalPurple!85} 

\begin{document}\Huge\bfseries
Black \textcolor{lRP}{Light} \textcolor{RoyalPurple}{Regular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work yet :(

Comment: @UnPerrito Pasting the code above in a separate document doesn't work? You mean you get an error?

Comment: it works in another document, yep.

Comment: @UnPerrito then something is interfering with the command. You can know what by looking at the error. :) I can't say without taking a look.

Comment: This is the preamble :)

`\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`

Comment: @UnPerrito Sorry, I was asleep. I tried your preamble, everything works fine with me. What error are you getting?

Comment: @alennano oh yes, I'm sorry, add to it: 
`\definecolor{light-RoyalPurple}{RoyalPurple}{0.85} `

Comment: @UnPerrito Ah well, as explained in my answer, that is a wrong command, it will never work as you intend it to. Use the one I have in my code example.

Comment: @alennano Oh, I was waking up xD. I wanted to say: `\colorlet{lRP}{RoyalPurple!85} `

Comment: Can you paste the error you're getting?

Comment: I was getting a problem with "Light-RoyalPurple" so now I changed it for lRP and now it's working haha I'm sorry! Eu fico muito obrigado com você!

Comment: `\definecolor` doesn't expect `hsb` or `HSB`, [as it seems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433015). Do you know how to actually use `hsb` color parameters with xcolor? Or does the hsb model only work with named colors?

Comment: Very good answer.